# Laravel mass assignment [1452] error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

MySql throws error an error when trying to create a new instance of a model. The `user_id` field is valid, I've tried to set it manually but it didn't work either. User with id `1` exists.

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`production_paperclip`.`widgets`, CONSTRAINT `widgets_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into `widgets` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2014-07-21 02:14:12, 2014-07-21 02:14:12))
```

Query:

```
\Widget::create(array(
        'title'             => \Lang::get('widget.news_localizer.install.title'),
        'strictName'        => self::strictName,
        'userSettings'      => null,
        'description'       => \Lang::get('widget.news_localizer.install.description'),
        'bodyTemplateName'  => 'admin.dashboard.widgets.news_localizer.index',
        'user_id'           => \Auth::id(),
        ));
```

Model:

```
class Widget extends \Eloquent
{
   use SoftDeletingTrait;

   protected $fillable = array('*');
   /**
    * Get the user which installed the widget
    * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    */
   public function user()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
   }
}
```

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('widgets', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        // Name
        $table->string('title', 256);
        $table->index('title');

        // Strict name
        $table->string('strictName')->unqiue();

        // User settings
        $table->text('userSettings')->nullable();

        // A short description
        $table->string('description')->nullable();

        // Body template name
        $table->string('bodyTemplateName');

        // User
        $table->integer('user_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('no action');

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Widget` model change

```php
protected $fillable = array('*');
```

to

```php
protected $guarded = array('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
```

or

```php
protected $fillable = array('title', 'strictName', 'userSettings', 'description', 'bodyTemplateName', 'user_id');
```

In other words you have to explicitly specify fillable fields (white list), or guarded fields (black list). **`*` works only** for `$guarded`, not `$fillable` and error message clearly shows that. You have only timestamp fields being populated:

```sql
insert into `widgets` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (2014-07-21 02:14:12, 2014-07-21 02:14:12)
```